# a cheap Laser / IR solution for 2D mapping?

Tags: navigation, mapping, sonar, costmap, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

does anyone know of a relatively cheap sensor solution for 2D mapping? don't need it to be (laser) accurate. just good enough to build a 2D map for some basic indoor navigation job.

Sonar, IR, anything that might do the job.

**UPDATE:**
i also found [LiDAR-Lite](http://pulsedlight3d.com) i guess its fairly new to the marker. it is also very cheap but it should be modified to cover 360 degree around it. anyone tried it before?

Thanks for the ideas n answers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208977/a-cheap-laser-/-ir-solution-for-2d-mapping?/) by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2015-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's a Poor man lidar, that could be used for mapping.  It uses a sharp IR sensor and a servo.

http://www.pirobot.org/blog/0014/

The xv-11 laser is a fairly cheap setup for under $100 on eBay.

http://wiki.ros.org/xv_11_laser_driver

---

Originally posted by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) with karma: 258 on 2015-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-13**:
hello! have you ever tried a PML before? i thought i'd eliminate the moving parts and build an ir_ring instead, any ideas?

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2015-05-13**:
I've done both suggestion second is better.  I was never able to get a good map with the IR moving on a servo and my robot moving.  Probably could have built a decent map if I had stitch several static maps together.

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-13**:
by second, you mean IR ring or xv-11?

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2015-05-13**:
xv-11.  I haven't done the IR ring but it should work.  Any particular reason for no moving parts?

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-14**:
just for eliminating moving parts (risk of mechanic failure) and also i wanna put a cover over the robot, panning IR will need a wide opening in the robot's cover. but I'm thinking a ring may have some overlapping and blind spot problems.

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2015-05-14**:
I like the idea, I'll have to follow up with you to see how well it works out.  You could use a couple of bumpers in the front to protect against blind spots.

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-14**:
yea sure, lets see what i end up buying and we'll see how it works out. Lidar is tempting though lol do you happen to know of a working exploration package? I'm stuck.

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2015-05-14**:
Sorry I don't.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not know if it will be cheap enough.

http://www.robotshop.com/en/rplidar-360-laser-scanner.html

ROS node can  be found here:

https://github.com/robopeak/rplidar_ros

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-05-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-13**:
Hi! its looks the same as xv_11 lidar, have you tried it? are these two different products?

**Comment by [Trexter101](https://answers.ros.org/users/22413/trexter101/) on 2015-05-13**:
I have tried the rplidar with hector slam it works great!

**Comment by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) on 2015-05-15**:
RPLidar works great with GMapping too for me